# Как перенести на новую строку в JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
jQuery('.keyword_m').text("Processing will take about XX minutes (тут перенос строки).Please, don't close.");
```

Не как не могу сделать перенос строки. `\r\n <br/>` все пробовали.
Какие еще есть варианты ?

Comment: Измените .text на .html и тогда используйте <br>

Comment: Ааааааа, спасибо. Все вышло

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста:)

Answer (score -1):

```js
    jQuery('.keyword_m').text("Processing will take about XX minutes. \n Please, don't close.");
```

```css
    body { white-space: pre-line; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="keyword_m"></span>
```